# Why ".kt" extension is sometimes visible and sometimes not?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In on of my Android Studio Kotlin projects, sometimes .KT is shown and sometimes not, in the Project explorer, in the Activity folder.

What is the criteria used by Android Studio to show or hide the .KT extension ?

Thanks

Comment: When the file contains a class with the same name as the file, it hides the .kt extension

Comment: I am not sure that this is a bug. I have been able to suppress the ".kt" extension after I understood that declaring 2 classes in the same file forced Android Studio to show the ".kt" extension (so after moving one class into one file then the ".kt" extension does not show anymore). But there is still another file with only one class in it that the ".kt" extension is still shown.

Comment: Great, thanks Erwin, that was the 2nd reason of the other file still showing its extension ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

One activity file should contain only one class.

One activity file class name declaration must correspond to the good filename (filename must equals class name).

Answer (score 23):

If a kotlin file has exactly one `outer class/object/interface` as the name of the file, then Android studio just shows the name without extension.

Answer (score 4):

This could happen if activity does not meet one or more of these points:

1. One activity file should contain only one class.
2. One activity file class name declaration must correspond to the good filename (filename must equals class name).
3. There are no top-level declarations (constants, variables).

Comment: Additional condition to this 3rd point, top-level declarations which are private are allowed to exist to show without extension.